# Sisense: Self table join for historical data reporting

Tags: mysql, business-intelligence

Let me start with an example. Suppose I have the following snippet of a slowly changing dimension table containing info about customers:

```
key  id      name  country      valid_from  valid_to    version
1    abcxyz  John  Switzerland  2012/01/01  2014/01/01  1
20   abcxyz  John  Germany      2014/01/01  2017/01/01  2
...
```

As you can see, every change in a customer's info is recorded as a new entry in the table with the same id, but the version incremented by 1 (*key* field is primary key of table)

This table is then imported in an Sisense ElastiCube, and then I have access to it from the Dashboard web app.

My question is: How can I create a widget which shows me all customers that moved from country A to country B? (if A were Switzerland and B were Germany, John would show up in the report)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that (id, version) is unique and that there are no gaps in the version sequence, this query would give you the customers who moved from one country to another.

Please note that it does **not** give you the most recent version of the customer record, but rather the version of the record when the change occurred. John could be living in Italy in version 3, but the query would still give you the Germany record.

```
select a.key as moved_from_key
      ,b.key as moved_to_key
  from customers a
  join customers b on(
       b.id      = a.id
   and b.version = a.version + 1 -- The version following A
  )
 where a.country = 'Switzerland'
   and b.country = 'Germany';
```

Comment: Hi there, Ronnis. Yes, this is correct, but I am not interested in solving the problem with SQL code, I would like to create a widget in Sisense's dashboard to do this. I was unable to do this, however, because I cannot put 2 different filters on the same field (country) in Sisense